# How to catch color dialog event by using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to paint text color in the textarea. My code is working, but some controls are not true.

I want it follows these steps:

1. User type text to textarea and select it (selectedText).
2. Click color button (in my code with `id="color"`). A color dialog will appear, user will choose a color and click OK.
3. If `OK` is clicked, my code will get `$("#color").val()` and send to another functions.

But, please checking help me, it gets `$("#color").val()` before the color dialog appears.

```
<input id="color" type="color" onclick="Color()" />
<textarea id="content-panel" cols="100" rows="20" onkeyup="PreView()"></textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>

var _string = "";
function Color()
{
  GetSelectedText($("#color").val());
  $("#content-panel").focus();
}

function GetSelectedText(type)
{
  var temp = document.getElementById("content-panel");
  // check if text is selected
  if(temp.selectionStart !== undefined)
  {
    startPos = temp.selectionStart;
    endPos = temp.selectionEnd;

    // get selectedText from startPos to endPos
    selectedText = temp.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    startString = temp.value.substring(0, startPos);
    endString = temp.value.substring(endPos, temp.value.length);
  }
  $("#content-panel").val(startString + "[" + type + "]" + selectedText + "[/" + type + "]" + endString);
  PreView();
}

function PreView()
{
  var _temp = document.getElementById("content-panel");
  _string = _temp.value; // get new value

  _string = _string.replace(/\[(#(\w{6})+?)\]/g, "<font color=\"$1\">");
  _string = _string.replace(/\[\/(#(\w{6})+?)\]/g, "</font>");

  var lines = _string.split("\n");
  var line = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
  {
    line += lines[i] + "<br>";
  }
  $("#preview").html(line);
}
```

So, my question is: How to catch an event when user click `OK` of "color dialog"? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, instead of `onclick`, use `onchange`:

```
<input id="color" type="color" onchange="Color()" />
```

This fires an event when the value of `#color` has changed, i.e. when you have picked (and confirmed) a new color.

```js
var _string = "";
function Color()
{
  GetSelectedText($("#color").val());
  $("#content-panel").focus();
}

function GetSelectedText(type)
{
  var temp = document.getElementById("content-panel");
  // check if text is selected
  if(temp.selectionStart !== undefined)
  {
    startPos = temp.selectionStart;
    endPos = temp.selectionEnd;

    // get selectedText from startPos to endPos
    selectedText = temp.value.substring(startPos, endPos);

    startString = temp.value.substring(0, startPos);
    endString = temp.value.substring(endPos, temp.value.length);
  }
  $("#content-panel").val(startString + "[" + type + "]" + selectedText + "[/" + type + "]" + endString);
  PreView();
}

function PreView()
{
  var _temp = document.getElementById("content-panel");
  _string = _temp.value; // get new value

  _string = _string.replace(/\[(#(\w{6})+?)\]/g, "<font color=\"$1\">");
  _string = _string.replace(/\[\/(#(\w{6})+?)\]/g, "</font>");

  var lines = _string.split("\n");
  var line = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
  {
    line += lines[i] + "<br>";
  }
  $("#preview").html(line);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="color" type="color" onchange="Color()" /><br />
<textarea id="content-panel" cols="50" rows="5" onkeyup="PreView()"></textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

*(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4vnmoh9/)*